# simple login form in mvc-5 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

i just started mvc-5 and i am unable to find example in mvc-5 for the people who just started using with core(c#) i used mvc-5 but with angularjs so when i try to use with the core of c# i am not able to even create a login form,

i want your help guys i created a controller which looks like the following(i am showing whole pages of my content for better understanding)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace mvcerp2.Controllers
{
    public class logintestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: logintest
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

my Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
namespace mvcerp2.Models
{
    public class myloginmodel
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public void loginauth()
        {
            bool ispresentuser = false;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionstring",con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                ispresentuser = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ispresentuser = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how my view looks like

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="username"  />
        <input type="text" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
}
```

guys need your to get this, what i need to do to this code, to make this work,

it is not working, i am unable to login,

if user enter the username,password correctly, he should be redirected to welcome page or else, an error message should be poped up

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sir i created a model view controller but what i need to do to make this works, it is not working

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: edited my question a bit, this might help you

Comment: You have not shown the POST method!

Comment: please will you give me proper answer with explanation, it will help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133313/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mumbai-wadala).

Comment: I think I am late to the party but why not use the built in auth and work around it? is pretty easy to customize